# Infinite $digest Loop only on chrome for android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-chrome

Same code, different behaviour on desktop and on mobile.
I wrote an angular directive to build a simple video player.
In the timeupdate event I update a scope variable to sync the progress bar with the currentTime value of the video.
To get work I've to call `scope.$apply`.

```
angular.element(scope.videoElement).on("timeupdate", function () {

  scope.currentTime = scope.videoElement.currentTime;
  scope.percentage = ...;
  scope.$apply();
 });
```

and this is the template:

```
<div class="progress-value" ng-style="{'width': (percentage) + '%'}"></div>
```

If I don't call `scope.apply` the progress bar is not updated.
The first question is why?

The error:

> Infinite $digest Loop

is only on mobile (chrome). On desktop browser works fine. I don't understand why and I don't know how to manage it.

The other thing I don't understand is that if I call `$timeout(function(){})` instead of `scope.$apply();` in the code above I've the same infinite loop error.

the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mNQ4QC3MnnbeO8WjxgAS?p=preview

Comment: Plunker by any chance?

Comment: scope.$apply does same as $timeout(function(){}) -- so what is strange?. You didnt provide enough code to reproduce error, anyway in this particular case I would really simply set css style on element directly from java-script. timeupdate will happen quite often and there is no sense to trigger expensive digest each time.

Comment: `$timeout` is supposed to mimic `$safeApply`, meaning it won't trigger an infDig.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov: I agree with you that the simplest way is to set css style via javascript, but I'm curious about the why on all desktop browser works and in Chrome for Android not.